# How to convert Java String to Bytes32 in Java ? I am using web3j solidity wrapper to interact with Smart contract. I am getting following error:

Tags: ethereumj, java, web3j

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Input byte array must be in range 0 < M <= 32 and length must match type

I am trying to do as given below. I wanted to add the people but wrapper generated in web3j throwing the error above:

```
String s = "Rahul"; 
//System.out.println(s.getBytes().length);
Bytes32 b1=new Bytes32(s.getBytes());
contract.addPerson(b1,new Uint256(new BigInteger("35"));
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more information in the support of your question?

Comment: String s = "Rahul";  
  System.out.println(s.getBytes().length);
  Bytes32 b1=new Bytes32(s.getBytes());
  
  System.out.println("Add person --"+contract.addPerson(b1,new Uint256(new BigInteger("35"))));

Comment: I dont completely understand your question. However, if you want to work with Strings, Solidity also has a data type "string" which converts into a "Utf8String" in Web3J. Does that help?

Comment: My requirement is to convert Java string to byte32. Here i wanted to send the byte32 as an input to my contract.

Comment: Rahul, did u find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Not yet. Anybody knows Web3J API can help here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need solution but as it this is still unanswered and for other who may need.

`str.getBytes()` only returns byte of that string but actual process is but long.

The main problem is `Bytes32(byte[])` only supports 32 length `byte[]`.
Also keep in mind `Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(strValueInHex)` converts any Hex value of String to `byte[]`.

This is the process

Note: `"00"` = 1 length Hex & 2 length String

`String => Hex => 32 length Hex (ie. 64 length HexString) => byte[] => Bytes32`

Here is How I achieved String to Bytes:

String to 64 length HexString:

```
// String to 64 length HexString (equivalent to 32 Hex lenght)
public static String asciiToHex(String asciiValue)
{
    char[] chars = asciiValue.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
    }

    return hex.toString() + "".join("", Collections.nCopies(32 - (hex.length()/2), "00"));
}
```

64 length HexString to 32 length byte[]:

```
byte[] myStringInByte = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(asciiToHex("myString"));
```

32 length byte[] to Bytes32:

```
Bytes32 myStringInBytes32 = new Bytes32(myStringInByte);
```

Comment: I have wrote shorter method to do same task on my own question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/convert-string-to-bytes32-in-web3j/).

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use the JVM runtime library whenever possible; that code is usually of high quality, although exceptions do exist. In the following code I first create a `byte[]`, then derive a hex value by calling [DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary-byte:A-).

```
byte[] byteArray = "This string is converted to a byte array".getBytes();
String hexValue = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byteArray);
```

Comment: What is the vice versa of this code? I mean converting string from Byte32.

Answer (score 0):

`byte[] byte = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray("String Value");`