# Convert String to Bytes32 in web3j?

Tags: ethereumj, web3j, java

```
public String solFunction(String str) {
    byte[] byteValue = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str);
    Bytes32 strInBytes = new Bytes32(byteValue);
    try {
        Uint256 value = contract.showPoint(strInBytes).get();
        return value.getValue().toString();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// web3j generated java code for solidity program
public Future<Uint256> showPoint(Bytes32 byteValue) {
        Function function = new Function("showPoint", 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(rewardType), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
        return executeCallSingleValueReturnAsync(function);
    }
```

I am trying to send Bytes32 type argument to SmartContract function using web3j. It always throws exception

```
Input byte array must be in range 0 < M <= 32 and length must match type
```

I have already checked Numeric datatype converter of web3j and this solutions.
[issue reported in git web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/80)

This is my solidity program

```
contract MyContract {
    address public owner; // Store owner address
    mapping (address => mapping (bytes32 => uint)) value;

    function MyContract (uint initValue, bytes32 chkByte) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        reward[msg.sender][chkByte] = initValue;
    }

    function showAvailReward(bytes32 chkByte) constant returns(uint) {
            return value[msg.sender][chkByte];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLVED!!! LONG/Detailed METHOD!!! (**Shorter Version at bottom**)

The main problem was `Bytes32(byte[])` only supports 32 length `byte[]`.
Also keep in mind `Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(strValueInHex)` converts any HexString to `byte[]`.

This is the process:

`String => Hex => 32 length Hex (ie. 64 length HexString) => byte[] => Bytes32`

Note: `"00"` = 1 Hex length & 2 String length

Here is How I achieved String to Bytes:

String to 64 length HexString:

```
// String to 64 length HexString (equivalent to 32 Hex lenght)
public static String asciiToHex(String asciiValue)
{
    char[] chars = asciiValue.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
    }

    return hex.toString() + "".join("", Collections.nCopies(32 - (hex.length()/2), "00"));
}
```

64 length HexString to 32 length byte[]:

```
byte[] myStringInByte = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(asciiToHex("myString"));
```

32 length byte[] to Bytes32:

```
Bytes32 myStringInBytes32 = new Bytes32(myStringInByte);
```

Now myStringInBytes32 is accepted as by web3j's contract function.
In my case corrected `solFunction(String str)` is:

```
public String solFunction(String str) {
    String strInHex = asciiToHex(str);
    Bytes32 strInBytes32 = new Bytes32(Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(strInHex));
    try {
        Uint256 value = contract.showPoint(strInBytes32).get();
        return value.getValue().toString();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

If your solidity function returns data in Bytes32 then Here is how to get value from returned Bytes32 data.

```
String dataInString = hexToASCII(Numeric.toHexStringNoPrefix(dataInBytes32);
```

Function `hexToASCII`

```
public static String hexToASCII(String hexValue)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < hexValue.length(); i += 2)
        {
            String str = hexValue.substring(i, i + 2);
            output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

[String-to-Hex & Hex-to-String Help From Here](http://howtodoinjava.com/snippets-examples/convert-hex-to-ascii-and-ascii-to-hex/)

---

**SHORT/SIMPLIFIED Method:**

String to Bytes32:

```
public static Bytes32 stringToBytes32(String string) {
        byte[] byteValue = string.getBytes();
        byte[] byteValueLen32 = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(byteValue, 0, byteValueLen32, 0, byteValue.length);
        return new Bytes32(byteValueLen32);
    }
```

Bytes32 to String:

```
StringUtils.newStringUsAscii(varTypeBytes32.getValue());
```